# Connection refused: localhost:4200 favicon.ico 502 in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, connection-refused

I have create an angular project via

```
ng new project_name --style=scss
```

and then try to run via

```
ng serve
```

but getting error

[image]

[image]

removed and reinstalled the `node_modules` but all in vain.

Every time getting this error, please guide what to do!!!

**UPDATE 1**

Why I am not able to run `Angular` application on `localhost` (running on 192.168.X.X:4200) in my office pc but the same project I can run on `localhost` at my home

**UPDATE 2**

in hosts file, I have this. Is it OK?

127.0.0.1 localhost

::1 localhost

**Update 3**

I am quite sure, it is only the system config issue that's why it is blocking localhost and allowing 192.168.X.X but don't know where the problem lies.

Comment: Did you try `127.0.0.1`? Localhost is just an alias for this IP address. Maybe your PC in the office has different hosts settings. Please, let me know if this worked.

Comment: Worked but facing CORS problem [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254354/access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-http-localhost3000-from-origin-http-192-168](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254354/access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-http-localhost3000-from-origin-http-192-168), although I have set pre-flight option but didn't work

Comment: Would this help? https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuring-cors

Comment: Btw setting allow origin to `*` helps but try no to do this in production. This can be a huge security issue. :)

Comment: though `*` is a security concern but at least it should work but in my case it don't ;(

Comment: tried different CORS but none working. provided exceptions but none worked. [you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254354/access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-http-localhost3000-from-origin-http-192-168) I have provided different cors but all in vain.

Comment: Which OS are you using on your office pc? and is different from the one at home?

Comment: @Nickolaus Windows 7 x64 on both the computers

Comment: @WasiF propably the port 4200 is already used in the system  try running on a different   and make sure that post is not used by the system  port `ng serve --port 4401  `

Comment: @JoelJoseph Tested on different ports but same result 'connection refused'

Comment: I am quite sure, it is only the system config issue that's why it is blocking localhost and allowing 192.168.X.X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `Opera` browser for testing and it was my default browser and trying to access `localhost:4200` but every time `connection refused` then I test this on `Chrome`, it ran smoothly.

I checked proxy setting for both the browsers and there was no proxy enabled. Finally I reset settings and data in `Opera` and problem resolved.

Still, question is there!!! What was that hindering `localhost` ...

Comment: I already told you to change your local address :) ng serve --host 0.0.0.0. Good to see you found problem, have fun.

Comment: yes thank you, but that `--host 0.0.0.0` didn't work

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I also uses Opera and got the same problem. I reset the browser setting, now it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. I tried the above solutions, it didn't work. I am using a different port now. I used this command:

`-ng serve --port 0`

and I could see my app running on the new port.

Answer (score 0):

Put your favicon.ico file in assets folder and change the path in the index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `favicon.ico` file to your project root directory and update your `favicon` file **inject** code with the below code in the `head` of your `index.html` file. Thanks

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: but the same project at my home pc working fine. no need to add favicon to root or else where. I don't think so its favicon issue

Comment: It would be very helpful if you share any working example. Thanks

Comment: What info I should share, I too wonder about that? It's angular 7 project, running on windows 7 x64 and what else do I need to share? It also happens newly created project (with no addition)

Comment: Move your newly created project which have same issue on https://stackblitz.com. Thanks

Comment: It's not the problem with this project but every other project that I created and run smoothly but now they aren't running on `localhost` so I am quite sure it's the system config problem not with the project. Thanks

Comment: @WasiF did you try my answer below ?

Comment: @JoelJoseph trying

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to solve the same :

- Check your LAN proxy settings.

  In chrome Settings -> Advanced -> Open Proxy Settings -> LAN Settings -> make sure you unchecked "use proxy server for your LAN" or mark "bypass proxy server for local address" if you are using proxy

[image]

Also if the above settings didn't solve your problem probably the port `4200` is already used in the system try running app on a different port  `ng serve --port 4401`

Also make sure you clear browser cache to see the result

Comment: I checked in Chrome there was no proxy enabled and app run smoothly but during development I used Opera and Opera too doesn't have this proxy enabled. Finally I reset Opera settings and app worked on localhost. By the way Thanks Joel Joseph