# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/' from origin 'http://192.168.X.X:XX' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, angular, cors, angular7

Trying to access `Node server (http://localhost:3000)` from `Angular 7 (http://192.168.X.X)`

Set CORS i.e.

```
this.app.use(cors())
this.app.options('*', cors())
this.app.use(bodyParser.json())
this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

but getting

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:3000/' from origin
>   'http://192.168.X.X:XX' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Tried this middleware function

```
this.app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://192.168.X.X:4200');
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
});
```

but all in vain. Any help or suggestion that could resolve my issue???

## **************** Answer ****************

I was actually making a mistake by using `cors()` two times as

```
this.app.use(cors())
this.app.options('*', cors())
```

so when I used one of them, it worked fine :)

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38500226/441757. You need to add `app.options('*', cors())` to handle the CORS preflight OPTIONS request.

Comment: @sideshowbarker still same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these two

```
app.options("/*", function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
});
```

Comment: Ok, I'll check in a while. Maintaining angular app. Thanks for your kind response