# favicon.ico 502 error while getting image from static directory

Tags: node.js, image, express, favicon

I have set the static folder to access images

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(`assets/images`)))
```

and image is being stored successfully via multer and path assigned as

```
diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
       callback(null, 'assets/images')
    }
})
```

but getting error

[image]

and I tried to skip this error by adding a route

```
this.app.get('/favico.ico', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(204);
});
```

but nothing worked until now

**Update**

> Having this problem on localhost but working fine on Heroku

I have found another reason, I run my node app on `192.168.X.X` instead of localhost and got my image loaded

Now what can the problem that I am unable to get it on localhost

One more justification for that I am unable to host `angular 7` app on `localhost` but can run on `192.168.X.X`

Why is that? How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there was an issue in my `browser` configuration after resetting the `browser` settings and all that it got OK.

A complete solution and discussion lies here
[Connection refused: localhost:4200 favicon.ico 502 in angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54977872/connection-refused-localhost4200-favicon-ico-502-in-angular-7)